# Getting git pull request while push

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, pull-request

Today when i tried to push to my remote repo , i got this

```
Compressing objects: 100% (49/49), done.
Writing objects: 100% (49/49), 15.59 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 49 (delta 28), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: Create pull request for feature:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/xxxxxx/pull-requests/new?source=feature1&t=1
remote:
```

I never saw pull request thing on command line.

I wanted to know how did that come and what does it mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation for [Git Hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks). The server you're pushing to has installed a hook that gives you a notice after pushing. In this case, it seems the owner of the repo is requesting that you create a pull request. You should contact the owner with your question

Comment: I have two remotes one is `origin`  and other is  `Remote1`. I did `git push Remote1 feature1` . Now that Remote1 is my repo and i ahve not configured anything . Is there any chnace that can be done using local githooks